# Pyomo glpk solver Termination condition : other

Tags: python, pyomo, glpk

I'm fairly new to pyomo. I wrote a program and tried to solve it with glpk but I ended in the following problem:

```
{'Problem': [{'Name': 'unknown', 'Lower bound': -inf, 'Upper bound': inf, 'Number of objectives': 1, 'Number of constraints': 15361, 'Number of variables': 15369, 'Number of nonzeros': 46978, 'Sense': 'minimize'}], 'Solver': [{'Status': 'ok', 'Termination condition': 'other', 'Statistics': {'Branch and bound': {'Number of bounded subproblems': 0, 'Number of created subproblems': 0}}, 'Error rc': 0, 'Time': 0.2313551902770996}]}
```

The problem I guess is on the termination condition and all decision variables using model.pprint() seem to have the values of None.

Any idea how i could make the script to run properly and a find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us a minimum reproducible example? It's hard to tell what's going on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.